# Typescript Class use Interface as type instead of implement

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface, es6-class

I'm looking for at way to mimick the C# way of using/implementing Interfaces. In short I'm trying to replicate the following code:

```
interface EBook {
    function read();
}

class EBookReader {

    private $book;

    function __construct(EBook $book) {
        $this->book = $book;
    }

    function read() {
        return $this->book->read();
    }

}

class PDFBook implements EBook {

    function read() {
        return "reading a pdf book.";
    }
}

class MobiBook implements EBook {

    function read() {
        return "reading a mobi book.";
    }
}
```

Using implements works fine however I cannot mimick the Class EBookReader way of using Ebook as a type.

codepen with my code mockup: http://codepen.io/Ornhoj/pen/gLMELX?editors=0012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> using Ebook as a type

The case is sensitive.

```
interface IEBook {
    read();
}

class EBookReader {
    book: IEBook;

    constructor(book: IEBook) {
        this.book = book;
    }

    read() {
        this.book.read();
    }

}

class PDFBook implements IEBook {
    read() {
        console.log("reading a pdf book.");
    }
}

class MobiBook implements IEBook {
    read() {
        console.log("reading a mobi book.");
    }
}
var pdf = new PDFBook();
var reader = new EBookReader(pdf);
reader.read();
```

Test this code [in the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IEBook%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20read()%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%20%0D%0Aclass%20EBookReader%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20book%3A%20IEBook%3B%0D%0A%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(book%3A%20IEBook)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.book%20%3D%20book%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20read()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.book.read()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20PDFBook%20implements%20IEBook%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20read()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22reading%20a%20pdf%20book.%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%20%0D%0Aclass%20MobiBook%20implements%20IEBook%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20read()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22reading%20a%20mobi%20book.%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Avar%20pdf%20%3D%20new%20PDFBook()%3B%0D%0Avar%20reader%20%3D%20new%20EBookReader(pdf)%3B%0D%0Areader.read()%3B).

Comment: Love it when it's a simple case-sensitive error which has kept me at bay for one-and-a-half day. +1 and correct answer given.